# Map elements in a list to positions in another list

Tags: java

Imagine we have two lists and want to know the postions of elements from one list in the other. To illustrate:

```
List<String> one = Arrays.asList("B", "I", "G");
List<String> another = Arrays.asList("L", "A", "R", "G", "E");
```

Result would be:

```
[-1, -1, 3]
```

because neither B nor I occur in second list, but G does on 3rd position.

This is what I came with so far:

```
<E> List<Integer> indices(List<E> elements, List<E> container) {
    List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>(elements.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        indices.add(container.indexOf(indices.get(i)));
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Is there a faster solution that avoids internal loop in `List.indexOf()`?

Comment: @Sneaky I'm pretty sure that a dynamic-programming approach can improve it from n*m to a bound that may approach n+m, by preprocessing each array in sequence and merging both into a common data structure that can be inspected for overlap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Map`:

```
Map<String, Integer> otherMap = new HashMap<>(other.size());
int index = 0;
for(String otherElem : other) {
    otherMap.put(otherElem, index++);
}
```

And then:

```
for(String oneElem : one) {
    Integer index = otherMap.get(oneElem);
    indices.add(index == null ? -1 : index);
}
```

Doing so, you get the index directly instead of iterating on a potentially very big list each time you look for and index.

Comment: Yeah, came to the same idea just now :-) Your code is better than mine, I'll use yours if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` that would map every character to its position. Then use `HashMap` method `.containsKey()` to find out, if a certain String is present in the field and `.get()` to find out the position.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> another;

for (String str : one) {

    if (another.contains(str)) {
        result.add(another.get(str));
    } else {
        result.add(-1);
    }
}
```